# How to get current logged in user id in access-db 2016

Tags: ms-access

I'm making a students management system in access, in which I have made a signup table named as `students` and after that I made it's form and it's saving data in table and after that I made login form which is working fine, and after logging in it's showing personal details form (I have set that) and which also stores data, and in personal details table I have a field named `student_id_fk` which stores the primary key of that user which is logged in but I am confused that how to get currently logged in user id is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use `Environ("username")`

Alternatively you may use below function or call Windows API

```
Function getUsername() As String
    Dim WshNetwork As Object
    Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    getUsername = WshNetwork.UserName
    Set WshNetwork = Nothing
End Function
```